# Fitting a tableView into its parent UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I dropped a TableView into my ViewController using Storyboard and I want it to be filled without any margins like the lower ViewController with TableView in the image below.

[image]

I tried some suggestions from the answers in other similar questions but didn't work at all.

Some say I need to set PIN. and I tried it like below:

[image]

I've typed '0' for all 4 constraints but this is what I got:

[image]

This AutoLayout thing makes me really hard to layout things automatically, unlike it's name.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Click on Resolve Auto layout Issues after that click on Update frames as shown into below image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the animated answer. Helped me a lot!

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the Document Outline, tap the yellow arrow:
[image]

Tap the yellow triangle:
[image]

Then select `Update Frames`, `Fix Misplacement`.
[image]

This will fix the misplaced view. Alternatively you could have resized the table view before specifying the constraints.

I recommend you have a look at an auto layout tutorial, for example [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2).

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick. and thanks for the link as well.